# Why in snes9x (on Ubuntu), if the joystick is disconnected it isn't recognized again?

Tags: controllers, snes, ubuntu

SNES9x works with my USB joystick alright, but if I need disconnect this joystick (even with the ROM paused), when I connect it again it doesn't work anymore.

Why?

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Do you need to restart the emulator or the PC for it to work again?

Comment: What version of SNES9x are you using, and have you contacted the developers about this issue? Emulator ports on Linux are notoriously unstable as well.

Comment: @MatthewRead, yes, if I restart the snes9x it works fine.

Comment: @Xkeeper using `snes9x -v` I got:

    Snes9x 1.52 for unix
    Reading config file /etc/snes9x/snes9x.conf.
    Sound buffer size: 12800 (3200 samples)
    Port 1: Pad #1. Port 2: <none>. 
    Error opening the ROM file.

But I use it by gui snes9x-gtk. I didn't tried contact the developers yet =//

Comment: It's probably just a driver thing, this happens with most joysticks and most games it seems.

Comment: [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) might know. I do not know off the top of my head, but here's conjecture: See if plugging and unplugging the joystick makes a different device node in /dev.

Comment: For the record this seems to be true on Windows 10 and not just Linux. I think SNES9x only looks for controllers when you first start the app. If something drops it never looks for it to be re-added. I always have to restart to see the controller again..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you'd need to be frequently unplugging your joystick mid-game, but why not just take a save state, play musical chairs with your usb devices, restart snes9x, and reload your save state?